# How to read file from folder and apply pivot to each file and write pivoted dataframe to folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I have a folder with csv files with tables in them.

I have confirmed my pivot function and below code is what I need:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['FieldTitle','Value']).tolist()

pivoted_df = pd.pivot_table(df.fillna('missing'), index=cols, columns='FieldTitle', values='Value', aggfunc='first').reset_index().replace('missing', np.nan)
```

How do I apply these two lines of code to every file in the folder, while writing the `pivoted_df` to another folder?

I tried this code, but I cant get pandas to read the file to do the manipulation:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

directory = os.path.join('~/Desktop/folder_path')
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
       if file.endswith(".csv"):
           f=open(file, 'r')
           for i in f:
               df = pd.read_csv(i)
               cols = df.columns.difference(['FieldTitle','Value']).tolist()
               pivoted_df = pd.pivot_table(df.fillna('missing'), index=cols, \
                                           columns='FieldTitle', values='Value', \
                                           aggfunc='first').\
                                           reset_index().replace('missing', np.nan)

               pivoted_df.to_csv('~/Desktop/folder_path/file_name_{}'.format(file))

           f.close()
```

Comment: are you getting any kind of error message? and have you confirmed that it is itterating through the folder properly? Like have it print out the file names and make sure it is finding the files.

Comment: its not giving me any errors or printing the file names at all. I tried that as well.

Comment: if you just ad a print(file) right above your 'if file.endswith(".csv")' and comment out the rest, you still get nothing?

Comment: @Jacobr365 still getting nothing

Comment: @Jacobr365 when I added the full path it prints the file name now. But says that the file doesnt exist at the `open`. Confirmed file is in the folder

Comment: so i added double '\' to my path so it was "C:\\Users\\Person\\Desktop\\test" and it started working. also you need to join the file with the directory when you open. so it should be `f = open(os.path.join(directory, file))`

Comment: @Jacobr365 that did it for me. If you answer ill accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need double '\' for windows so your path would be "C:\\Users\\Person\\Desktop\\test"

You need to combine the file name and path when you go to open it.

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
       if file.endswith(".csv"):
           f=open(file, 'r')
```

The `file` variable is holding just the name of the file and not the full path. And, since the file is not in the current working directory you need the path. The solution is to change it to:

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
       if file.endswith(".csv"):
           f = open(os.path.join(directory, file))
```

The `os.path.join()` combines the directory and file name to get the full path.